# how to prefix a unique string to all filename of files in a directory

Tags: perl, shell, find, exec, rename

anything perl, shell script to append filenames with unique string.  Example -

```
ip1/xxx.v 
ip1/xxy.v 
ip1/ip1.v 
ip1/ip1_zxy.v
```

To be renamed as

```
ip1/ip1_xxx.v 
ip1/ip1_xxy.v 
ip1/ip1.v 
ip1/ip1_zxy.v
```

Comment: `perl -pe 's|^(\w+)/\K(?!\1)|${1}_|'`

Answer (score 0):

For shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in */; do
  for file in $dir/*; do
      mv "$file" "$dir/${dir//\/}_$file"
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)'s `rename` :

```
rename -n 's@([^/]+)/([^/]+)$@$1/$1_${2}@' $PWD/ip1/*
```

Remove `-n` switch to stop the tests.

https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/File-Rename/rename.PL